# Mysql Database Recovery

Tags: mysql, recovery, data-recovery

Is any possible to recover the data which is deleted accidently in mysql 5 and linux environment. My friend deleted one database from mysql in his linux machine accidently is there any chance to recover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was binary logging enable for the mysql database?  if there are binary logs for that db, you can try recovering the deleted data from there.  if there are no binary logs,no mysqldumps, or backups then i think your friend is out of luck.

Comment: I think Binary Logs is available. Is any software is there to recover ?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is maintained by an ISP, ask the support if it's possible to do a rollback. Most ISPs / Server-Hosting-Services do automated backups of your server (-files), so your data may be not completely lost.